# Why are expressions not working for fields within third and fourth levels in QGIS 3.30.2 QField forms?

Tags: qgis

"Control visibility by expression" on QGIS/QFIELD

I'm using QGIS 3.30.2 to create a QField form. I was trying to control the visibility of some fields using expressions, but it is not working properly, namely on fields within the third and fourth levels, as follows:

1st level - working properly on qfield:

[image]

2nd level - working properly on qfield:

[image]

3rd and 4th level - not working on qfield, appear independently of the previous answer:

[image]

Any tips?